# How to put json script in a file to use in PowerShell using cURL

Tags: json, powershell, curl

I'm trying to pass a json script to curl using powershell. It seems to work if I hard code it right into a variable escaping the double quotes with backslash, but I want to pass the json in a file. I tried putting the json script in a separate json file and then use get-content and throw it in a variable, but it does not seem to work I get a "Validation_Error".  Any suggestions

This Works

[image]

But I want to do something like this

$json = Get-Content C:\test.json

curl -v -X POST https://api.paypal.com/v1/invoicing/invoices/ \ -H "Content-Type:application/json" \ -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \ -d $json

Comment: "it does not seem to work"  What does that mean?

Comment: When I put the script in a file it gives me the following validation error:

Comment: {"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","message":"Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for OBJECT (from line:1, column:3","information_link"

Comment: Does `Get-Content C:\test.json -Raw` work?  That loads the content into a single string instead of an array with one string per line.

Comment: No I still get the validation error

Comment: By removing the single quotes and adding -raw it was able to work thanks @BaconBits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$json = Get-Content C:\test.json -Raw
```

By default `Get-Content` loads into an array of strings.  The `-Raw` flag forces it to load into a single string.

You should also be able to do this and tell curl to read the file itself:

```
curl -v -X POST https://[...] -d @test.json
```

From the man page:

> If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a file name to read the data from[.]

Answer (score 0):

Remember curl in PoSH, is really this...

```
Get-Alias -Name curl

CommandType Name
----------- ----
Alias       curl -> Invoke-WebRequest
```

... if you were not aware. The is another alias for Invoke-WebRequest as well.

If you want to use true curl in your PoSH session, you must use the full UNC to the executable (curl.exe) and that .exe extension is required or PoSH will use the alias above.

```
Get-Help -Name Invoke-WebRequest -Examples
Get-Help -Name Invoke-WebRequest -Full
```

So, for Invoke-WebRequest, the JSON must be in the body. Something like...

```
Invoke-WebRequest -uri "blahblahwhatever.com/api/uri" -Method POST -Body $JSON
```

So, virtually all the cmdlets have aliases, thus when we use commands we know that are really aliases, we must keep in mind what the real underlying cmdlet can and cannot do.

Comment: Note, that this answer, while correct at the time, is now obsolete. Most recent Window 10 and Windows Server 2019 have curl installed, and it is no longer an alias

Comment: Not true. WIn10 current / insider still has it.  Get-CimInstance -ClassName  [Microsoft Windows 10 Pro and Insider Preview 10.0.18363 / 10.0.19624],   [PSVersion  5.1.18362.752 / 5.1.19624.1000 ],   Get-Alias -Definition Invoke-WebRequest [Alias  curl -> Invoke-WebRequest ]  I don't have a WS 2019 up right now to check.  To use the real curl on Win10, you must use the full name curl.exe, or PowerShell will default to the alias as per [PowerShell command precedence](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence?view=powershell-7).

Comment: I guess anybody reading this will have to check by themselves. I am getting `Get-Alias -Name curl` -> `Get-Alias: This command cannot find a matching alias because an alias with the name 'curl' does not exist.` and `Get-Command curl` -> `Application curl.exe 7.55.1.0 C:\Windows\system32\curl.exe` on Windows 10 Pro v.1909 (18363.900)

Comment: Yeppers I guess the will, because even, this...  Get-Alias -Name curl

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           curl -> Invoke-WebRequest,   I get the alias results, and I just updated to the lastest inside build and v2004.  It's still there.

Comment: it seems that it is the version of PowerShell that makes a difference; not Windows OS. Powershell 7 does not use alias any more. PS 5.1 does

Comment: Correct, but your original comment was Win10 and beyond/WS2019 proper which all still default to Windows PowerShell. PSCore has to explicitly be manually installed as we know.  There is no announcement from Microsoft about PSCore ever becoming the default anytime soon. So we all must specially be careful to clarify particular we want others to rememeber or know.